# AADSTS90093 when signed in as Global Admin

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to do the initial consent for an application registered in Azure AD that requires access to read directory data.  I've activated my Global Admin role in Privileged Identity Management and hit the following URL in a new browser window.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxx&response_type=code&prompt=admin_consent&redirectUri=xxx
```

I'm getting the AAD error page saying I need to be an admin:

> Additional technical information:
>   Correlation ID: 41ab9f3d-7430-4c46-aff4-a28e7f5398c2
>   Timestamp: 2016-05-12 15:03:27Z
>   AADSTS90093: This operation can only be performed by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your organization's administrators.

Why doesn't it recognize me as an admin?

Comment: Are you using you assigned the user (that is trying to log in) Global Admin role from users configuration page ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but I am using [PIM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-privileged-identity-management-configure/) to temporarily activate the Global Admin role as needed.  The user is not assigned as a permanent Global Admin.

Comment: I've tried this again with a user who is a permanent Global Admin and it worked.  So it seems to be an issue with PIM?

Comment: That was my initial doubt. Could be yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a delay between the role assignment and when the application consent experience recognized the change. While a user may appear in their new role both in the Azure AD PIM experience as well as in the Azure management portal, the consent page required either 10-15 minutes, for the user to sign in again, to recognize the new role assignments.